# I can't execute a binary file on ARM version of ubuntu!

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, arm

I'm using an ARM version of ubuntu 12.04 and I need to run a binary file (to install a program). However, when I do so, it returns an error:

```
$ ./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run
bash:./qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.4.1.run cannot execute binary file
```

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Edit your question and post the complete error message.

Comment: And add the output of `file <your_binary>`, eg: `file file.run`

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an ARM architecture you can't run native a binary for x86. Without a recompilation, that's not possible.

On the [download page](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) are no binaries for ARM.

You could use [QEMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU), a hosted virtual machine monitor to start x86 applications.

Comment: both upvoted! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't run this file, because it is for x86 cpu, not arm.

Comment: Both upvoted! :-)